# ASP.NET MVC - AjaxContext

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontext

I've tried to inspect the AjaxContext that ASP.NET-MVC uses on for instance Ajax Actionlinks and their onSucces, onComplete etc. clientside functions. But I don't understand very much of it... Where is the documentation on this thing?

**Does anybody know how to I get the 'target' or 'srcElement' (e.target or window.event.srcElement) when I am in a onSuccess or onComplete javascript event?**

```
<%=Ajax.ActionLink(
"LinkText", "Action", New With {.Controller = "ControllerName"}, 
New AjaxOptions With {
    .UpdateTargetId = "divElement", 
    .OnSuccess = "function(ajaxContext) {console.log(ajaxContext);}"
}) %>
```

Which results in:

```
<a 
    href="/Popout/ApplicationCodePopout"
    onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(
        this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), 
        { 
            insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, 
            updateTargetId: 'divElement', 
            onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, 
                function(ajaxContext) {console.log(ajaxContext);}
            )
        }
    );"
>LinkText</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the onSuccess method to this:

```
<%=Ajax.ActionLink(
"LinkText", "Action", New With {.Controller = "ControllerName"}, 
New AjaxOptions With {
    .UpdateTargetId = "divElement", 
    .OnSuccess = "function(ajaxContext) {debugger;}"
}) %>
```

(**Note the debugger keyword**)

Then you can break into it using VS2008 (assuming IE, if you're using Firefox, then install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as Jake said) and then you can use the quick watch window (in VS or equivalent in Firebug etc) to view the object and it's properties/ methods etc.

As for some documentation, check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/rpxlib/source/browse/trunk/src/RPX.Web.MVC/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js?spec=svn2&r=2) link to see the code comments, and [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/03/04/the-mvc-framework-a-deep-dive-on-the-client-ajax-api.aspx) article for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you need to get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed (If you havnot already done so do it now :) Now start using [console.log](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) in your code to help you find out what properties and functions each object has available. Try typing in console.log(document) - You can do this in the Console window in the textbox (next to the >>>). Notice how you can click on the links in the console to interigate and see what properties and functions the object has available.

Comment: Remember to remove the console.log statements after you get it working too! Internet explorer and other browsers do not support console.log as it is part of firebug

Comment: or just do `console && console.log && console.log("loreum ipsum");` to only write to the console if it exists.

Comment: Ok, I already inspected it using some javascript function, this is a bit the same... Still I can't find any e.target or e.srcElement anywhere...?

Comment: can you post your javascript code, might be a little easier if we can look at what your doing

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend reading [jQuery in action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/). One of the best tech books I have ever read! Once you read that you will be able to start writing your own jQuery code and not have to worry about using a server side wrapper library that spits out javascript for you :)

Check it out
http://www.scribd.com/doc/8635225/jQuery-in-Action